# Citation for subset complement result

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, discrete-mathematics, permutations, math-history

Let $S = \{s_1, \ldots, s_n\} \subset \{1, \ldots, 2n\}$.  Consider two operations on $S$, unfortunately both called complement in different setting: let $A(S) = \{1, \ldots, 2n\} \setminus S$ (set theory) and let $B(S) = \{2n+1-s_1, \ldots, 2n+1-s_n\}$ (permutations). In general, $A(S) \ne B(S)$, but the sums of their elements are equal.

E.g., $S = \{1,2,5\} \subset \{1, \ldots, 6\}$ has $A(S) = \{3,4,6\}$, sum 13, and $B(S) = \{2,5,6\}$, sum 13.

My question is *not* how to prove this (it's a nice proof appropriate for a discrete math course), rather **the history of this result or at least a citation**.  For me, this arose in looking at applications of permutations to fair division of indivisible goods.

Comment: One should not call $B$ complement; the term "reflection" seems more appropriate.

Comment: Good to hear from you, Marc.  The precedent for calling $B$ complement is, e.g., Eric Egge's "Restricted Symmetric Permutations" (Ann. Combin. 11, 2007).  For a permutation $\pi = (\pi_1, \ldots, \pi_n)$, he looks at the inverse, the reverse $(\pi_n, \ldots, \pi_1)$, and the complement $(n+1-\pi_1, \ldots, n+1-\pi_n)$.  The $S$ in my question is a particular "half" permutation.  Is reflection also in the literature?

Comment: You emphasize history in bold and in the bounty description; are you aware that there's a tag [tag:math-history]? It might be more useful in attracting the right people than some of the others.

Comment: Done.  Thanks, Joriki.